# How do I execute an async function that updates state when I instantiate a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-component

Currently I have App.tsx containing this bit.

```
<Route path="/car/:carModel" component={displayCarInfo} />

// @ts-ignore
const displayCarInfo = ({ match  }) => (
    <div>
        <CarInfoPage carModel={match.params.carModel}/>
    </div>
)
```

Later in my CarInfoPage component I have

```
let carModel  = props.carModel 
let [state, setState] = useState({carInfo : null, otherInfo: null})

async function getInfo(query : string) { 
    let carInfo = await GetCarInfo()   // make API call
    carInfo = processCarInfo()         // process data a little bit

    setState({                         // update state
            ...state,
            carInfo: carInfo
        })
}
```

How can I run this `getInfo()` function when the component is loaded so that `state.carInfo` is not `null`?

If I just run the function before I `render()` it is showing that the state is not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array.

```
let carModel  = props.carModel 
let [state, setState] = useState({carInfo : null, otherInfo: null})

async function getInfo(query : string) { 
  let carInfo = await GetCarInfo()   // make API call
  carInfo = processCarInfo()         // process data a little bit

  setState({                         // update state
    ...state,
    carInfo: carInfo
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getInfo(queryString);
}, []); // <-- runs only once when component mounts
```

**Note:** The initial state values *are* null so you may need to do some null checking before rendering anything.

Comment: Thanks, this was the right strategy. It's probably worth pointing out that since my API call uses `async-await` [this article](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/2tgtfjtuba-dont-async-await-especially-in-useeffect) about using `asyc-await` inside effect hooks ended up being incredibly helpful